# Does the new app bundles replace abi splits?

Tags: android, android-studio, abi, android-app-bundle

**does abi split remplaced by apk bundle ?**
I created an Android app, and I want to split it  by ABIs in 4 APKs (x86, arm, armv7 and mips).
so I ask if can I use only generate signed app bundle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it is. if you want to use app bundle you should remove any split abi commands in gradle file

edit - answering to comment:

ABI split gives you the most savings when you are using native code, which is pretty common (even when devs don't even know that importing through gradle and using "java methods"). this is also well-known and pretty old resolution (so popular). app bundle is pretty new, so not every dev catched up already, and also bigger apk size reduction may take place when you are using a lot of images in `drawable` folders and strings. for example I've enabled ABI split in one of my projects (with only one native lib imported) and reduced size by 2 Mb. when I recently switched to app bundling then I've reduced apk size with additional ~0,5 Mb as this project is downloading a lot of images from network and don't have much drawables included, is also targeted to one country so it doesn't contain much translation strings

also note that when you split by ABI you still have APK files which you can easily install or send for someone, most of devices have 64bit ARM architecture. app bundle is creating universal `.aab` file and you have to declare all properties (lang, screen density, albo abi) for generating proper APK for particular device (using [bundletool](https://github.com/google/bundletool))

Comment: thank you but why some peoples use spliting by ABI until now !

Comment: added some explanation/suspicions in answer as it is too long for comment ;)